# Which RF Frequency and modulation is best

Tags: rf, radio

We are currently working on a project and we would like to get your advice about  which RF frequency and modulation would be most suitable                  to use for our      project.

The project is about a wrist that is use as a Home Detention        system for prisonners in custody in their appartment.

We are thinking to use a low frequency device for the wrist item but we are worried  about several things:

1./ Range , we need it around 50m radius

2./ Battery consumption of the wrist (we need it to work about 2-3 years)

3./ Accuracy of signal

4./ Concrete wall faraday cage effect

I would be happy if some RF specialist could give their opinion about which frequency range they would use, which protocol and which chip as well as some advice about antenna.

Thank you in advance for your help and wishing you a great day.

Regards

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866694/confirm-which-rf-to-use) to multiple sites.  StackExchange policy is against cross-posting.

Comment: These things exist. Why can't you buy some?

Comment: If you need it to transmit for 2-3 years without recharging, you probably need a car battery. So don't worry, they won't get far...

Comment: Get a 50 m extension cord.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### More detail is required...

Your question is not specific enough because which frequency bands, output powers, and modulation schemes you are allowed to use varies from country-to-country.

Things like "Accuracy" don't mean anything in this context and range is a multi-dimensional relationship between frequency band, modulation scheme, environment, and output power.

### In general...

- Lower frequencies penetrate structures better and experience less interference in indoor/urban environments (ergo, they are typically considered longer-range for constant power, but this isn't necessarily the case for any specific design problem).
- Lower frequencies require larger antennas and therefore larger devices (not good for wearable/carried devices)
- Because of their excellent long-range (penetration) abilities, these low-frequency bands are the most heavily regulated and utilized world-wide. They are also the first to be used historically, so there is a longer tradition of regulation for these bands.